# How to re-asking for declined Facebook Permissions with spring-social-security SocialAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Social with Spring Security to authenticate users and automatically create local accounts on my web app.

How do I provide the (auth_type=rerequest) when use with SocialAuthenticationFilter? ( /auth not /connect )